# UpdateProgress with Trigger not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updateprogress

I´m trying to use UpdateProgress with Triggers (see the code bellow) but when a button assigned as an asyncPostBackTrigger is clicked, the UpdateProgress doesn´t work.
If I remove the AssociatedUpdatePanelID property, the UpdateProgress control works. But I want to configure independent UpdateProgress so, I need to specify the
AssociatedUpdatePanelID property of UpdateProgress control.

Is this behaviour as it is supposed to be?

> **NOTE:** I do not want to intercept the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager
>   instance and manipulate the asyncronous request to manually display
>   and hide the UpdateProgress element. Is there a way to do that?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxExtensionsTest._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true"  runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <h2>
        Ajax Extensions Test
    </h2>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="content">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDataHora" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="progress1"  AssociatedUpdatePanelID="up1"  DynamicLayout="true" DisplayAfter="0" runat="server">
                        <ProgressTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <img alt="progress" src="loading.gif" />
                            </div>
                        </ProgressTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdateProgress>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit"  EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Get Current Date/Time" runat="server" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    <p>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
<script runat="server" language="csharp">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnSubmit);
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDataHora.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use AsyncPostBackTrigger and AssociatedUpdatePanelID then your only option is to handle events on the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager instance and manually display and hide the UpdateProgress element. There is code out there that runs on the server and injects the necessary JavaScript that could be encapsulated into a control to make doing this quite tidy.